# Swagger: How to make "Execute" button disabled if required parameters haven't been informed

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger UI Express to create docs to a very simple node API. It's more a "UI/UX" question, but is bothering me.

I have routes where a path parameter is required (client id, for instance), and I have documented this way. So, the parameter on Swagger UI is marked as required. However, user is able to click on "Execute" button without filling in the required parameter. This would not be a big problem if the page returned an error and let the user fill the required parameter and try again, but is not what it is happening. After clicking the button, a loading gif appears and keeps loading... Even if the user click on "Cancel" button, it is not stopping from loading.

On console, the follow error appears:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Error: Required parameter codCliente is not provided
    at index.js:233:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Bn [as buildRequest] (index.js:200:22)
    at actions.js:452:24
    at Object.dispatch (utils.js:177:16)
    at dispatch (<anonymous>:3665:80)
    at redux.js:546:12
    at wrap-actions.js:33:10
    at Object.r (system.js:175:26)
    at Object.executeRequest (system.js:487:14)
```

[Here is a screenshot of problem happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPMHr.png). We can see the parameter as required but the UI let you click on "Try it out" and then click on "Execute".

Here is an example of router and controller code:

```
const getByCod = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
  const { codCliente } = req.params;
  const cliente = await clientesService.getByCod(parseInt(codCliente, 10));

  return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ data: cliente });
};

clientesRouter.get(
  'clientes/:codCliente',
  authenticationMiddleware,
  authorizationMiddleware,
  getByCod,
);
```

And here my swagger path definition inside `swagger.json`:

```
"/clientes/{codCliente}": {
      "get": {
        "summary": '...',
        "description": '...',
        "tags": ["Clientes"],
        "security": [...],
        "parameters": [
          { 
            "in": "path",
            "name": "codCliente",
            "description": "Código do cliente",
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          [...]         
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: 1) What version of Swagger UI do you use? (dev tools > Console > evaluate `versions`) 2) Is the parameter actually marked as a) path parameter; b) required parameter in both your code AND Swagger UI? I'm asking because clicking "Execute" when a path param value is not provided is supposed to mark that parameter in red instead of sending the request - as in the demo https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/getPetById

Comment: First of all thanks for the spelling editing, my english is a work in progress. 
1) I'm not sure what do you mean about "dev tools > Console > evaluate versions", but my `swagger-ui-express` lib is 4.5.0. 
2) Yes, marked as required in both.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of Swagger UI showing the problematic path and its parameters? And also, if possible, the route declaration code with full annotations.

Comment: I edited the original question with the informations you've asked. Thanks.

Comment: Last (hopefully) question: Does your `swagger.json` use `"openapi": "3.0.x"` or `"swagger": "2.0"`?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0 version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.x, the parameter `type` must be wrapped into the `schema` keyword. The missing `schema` is what causes the issue with Swagger UI.

```json
        "parameters": [
          { 
            "in": "path",
            "name": "codCliente",
            "description": "Código do cliente",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {            <-----------
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        ],
```

The syntax without `schema` (as in your original example) is used in the previous version of the spec, OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`).

You can check your OpenAPI definitions for syntax errors using https://editor.swagger.io or [other validators](https://openapi.tools/#description-validators).

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help me. It worked perfectly. For anyone that is reading this, I recommend the Swagger Viewer extension to VSC. If I'd used it before, the problem probably wouldn't have occured.